# GAE Task Queue oddness

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I have been testing the taskqueue with mixed success. Currently I am
using the default queue, in default settings etc etc....

I have a test URL setup which inserts about 8 tasks into the queue.
With short order, all 8 are completed properly. So far so good.

The problem comes up when I re-load that URL twice under say a minute.
Now watching the task queue, all the tasks are added properly, but
only the first batch execute it seems.  But the "Run in Last Minute" #
shows the right number of tasks being run....

The request logs tell a different story. They show only the first set
of 8 running, but all task creation URLs working successfully.

The oddness of this is that if I wait say a minute between the task
creation URL requests, it will work fine.

Oddly enough changing the bucket_size or execution speed does not seem
to help. Only the first batch are executed. I have also reduced the
number of requests all the way down to 2, and still found only the
first 2 execute. Any others added display the same issues as above.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does this second batch stay in the Task Queue forever? What does the ETA column say, are all the tasks in the second batch overdue?

Comment: The tasks are "executed" or at least GAE thinks so, they do not remain in the queue.

Comment: When a tasks is executed, GAE executes a HTTP GET (or POST) to the URL of the task. Then, the task (url) is removed from the queue only if it returns http 200. If it returns 500 it remains in the queue and GAE will run it again.  
Check the logs carefully. Does your target url always return 200?

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't get any HTTP post or get in the logs. Its like the task never actually fires.

Answer (score 0):

When a task-queue ends in error : I believe it stays in your queue ..
Check that

Comment: The task queue does clear, which would make you assume it is executing. But there is nothing in the request logs. Its as it is not actually firing the task. Just removing it? Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry for the late ...
From my experience, when you do taskqueue : use log ! To see what's happening ... it's the only way to test that.
The only thing I can tell, is that it seems that your taskqueues don't throw exception (so they are removed after the job)